# JSON formatting column based upon added column of lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have two SharePoint lists.

List one has the following columns:

- Productgroup (text)
- Min (number, percentage)
- Max (number, percentage)

List two has columns:

- a lookup column for Productgroup
- Added columns for Min and Max connected to the chosen productgroup
- A column for the actual value (number, percentage)

I would like to have a conditional formatting for the column of the actual value so that

- If below [Productgroup].[Min] Background turns red.
- If above [Productgroup].[Max] Background turns orange.
- If between [Productgroup].[Min] and [Productgroup].[Max] background turns green.

I have tried the following as a start, but that didn't do the job.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Productgroep.Min]"
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField < [Productgroep.Min],'sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField < [Productgroep.Min],'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your additional columns for the lookup are in the view, you can access them using their internal names. So your format would look something like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Productgroup_x003a_Min]"
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(@currentField < [Productgroup_x003a_Min],'sp-field-severity--warning', '')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField < [Productgroup_x003a_Min],'Error', '')"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

Generally, additional fields for lookup columns have internal names of LookupColumn:OtherColumn which will be escaped (the colon changes to `_x003a_`). But you'll need to verify for sure by going to list settings and clicking on the additional column and looking at the name used in the URL.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to use it, but now the value has become invisible.

Comment: It seems that my reply got deleted (don't know why). I cannot repeat it in a comment due to the limited number of characters. What should I do?